# Constructor arguments cannot be passed for interface mocks

Tags: c#, moq

When I debug the code and read the line with the mockLessonplannerAFactory creation I get the error:

> *Constructor arguments cannot be passed for interface mocks.*

```
var mockSchoolclassCodeService = new Mock<ISchoolclassCodeService>();
var mockDateService = new Mock<IDateService>();
var mockLessonplannerAFactory = new Mock<ILessonplannerAFactory>(mockDateService.Object);
var mockLessonplannerBFactory = new Mock<ILessonplannerBFactory>(mockDateService.Object);

var service = new TimeTableService(mockUnitOfWork.Object, mockLessonplannerAFactory.Object, mockLessonplannerBFactory.Object, mockSchoolclassCodeService.Object);
```

My TimeTableService accepts instances of an interface type only. But the mockLessonplannerAFactory and BFactory... want in their constructor also an IDateService passed.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The mock that is created from the interface will have a default constructor because interfaces don't have a constructor. Remember you are mocking the interface not the concrete class.

"But the mockLessonplannerAFactory and BFactory... want in their constructor also an IDateService passed."

They are both mocked from interfaces, so there is no constructor. The mock class will create a default constructor which doesn't need to be passed anything.

Comment: yes I just realized by removing the passing of the mockDateService.Object that everything works fine.

Comment: This doesn't solve the real issue, how would you modify the mock setup

Comment: The mockLessonPlanAFactory and mockLessonPlanBFactory do not need constructor parameters. Any method or property that they have that use the objects normally passed in the constructor of the concrete implementation are themselves mock methods/properties and you set them up to return an appropriate value (otherwise you are not really mocking these objects). You set up the methods and properties as you need them.

Answer (score 3):

What you simply wanted to do...

1)create a normal interface mock.

```
  var mockDateService = new Mock<IDateService>();
```

2)Do a set up for accepting thing way that you need as constructor parameter.

```
mockDateService .Setup(s => s.ConstructorParam).Returns(constructorParamValue);
```