# Unit testing a controller with parameterized constructor in xunit project using MOQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-6.0, xunit.net

I am trying to write a xunit test method for my controller to test a JsonResult. But since the controller takes a parameter which will be injected from DI container, I am not sure how and where to pass this parameter in my test method.

**Controller:**

```
public class AppGuidelinesController : Controller
{
    private IAppGuidelineBLRepository appGuidelineRepos;

    public AppGuidelinesController(IAppGuidelineDBRepository dataRepos)
    {
        appGuidelineRepos = new AppGuidelineBLRepository(dataRepos);
    }
}
```

**Test method**

```
[Fact]
public void GetJsonData_Returns_JsonResult()
{
    // Arrange
    Mock<IAppGuidelineDBRepository> dbReposMock = new Mock<IAppGuidelineDBRepository>();

    var appGuideline = new AppGuideline()
    {
        Id = 1
    };

    dbReposMock.Setup(repo => repo.AddGuideline(appGuideline));

    var controller = new AppGuidelinesController(dbReposMock.Object);

    var mockControllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
    controller.ControllerContext = mockControllerContext.Object;

    AppGuidelineRequestModel appGuidelineRequestModel = new AppGuidelineRequestModel()
    {
        Id = 1
    };

    OperationStatus expectedOperationStatus = new OperationStatus
    {
        StatusType = hrlib_test.Enums.StatusType.Success
    };

    // Act
    var result = controller.AddGuideline(appGuidelineRequestModel);


    // Assert
    Assert.NotNull(result);
    Assert.IsType<JsonResult>(result);

    var actualOperationStatus = result.Value as OperationStatus;
    Assert.NotNull(actualOperationStatus);
    Assert.Equal(expectedOperationStatus.StatusType, actualOperationStatus.StatusType);
}
```

When I run the test, I am getting the below error

> System.ArgumentException : Constructor arguments cannot be passed for
> interface mocks.

Kindly help me to fix this issue and continue with other methods. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you creating a new `AppGuidelineBLRepository` in your controller in the first place? That should be injected too.

Comment: that is just a business class that I don't want to register with the DI

Comment: That's really bad practice, all business logic should be injected.

Comment: I see. thanks for the suggestion. Let me consider that. Can you help me out with the issue?

Comment: No, I can't help you with the issue here, I'm not sure this code can actually give you the error you say you have. Are you sure this is your actual code?

Comment: That error comes when you pass in parameters when creating the mock. e.g. `var foo = new Mock<IFoo>(someParameter)` but you don't do this here.

Comment: yes. this is the actual code.

Comment: hi @DavidG, Thanks. I found out the issue. It was not the test method that was causing the issue. there was a line I forgot to remove after testing which was causing the err.

Comment: Then you should delete this question since it is based on a typo and no longer useful to anyone.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like I forgot to remove a piece of test code from the constructor which was causing the actual error instead of the test method. After I removed it, the test passed. I found some help from this link => [Constructor arguments cannot be passed for interface mocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448824/constructor-arguments-cannot-be-passed-for-interface-mocks)

[image]